# jQuery selector problem with IE but works in ff

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, selector

I don't get why this code would work in FF and not IE. Can someone shed some light on this?

The `$(".ui-tabs-nav li a")` seems to be the problem. In IE `this.text` is undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Y2dU/25/

Comment: this.text isn't a widely supported attribute.  YOu can use `$(this).text()` from jQuery and you can see it work here in IE7/IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PTBcf/

Answer (score 2):

`this` by itself is not a jQuery object. `$(this).text();` is probably what you're looking for.

After viewing your link I think you may be after something else.